# Firestore iterate over an object within a document's data REACT.JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to add some data inside the bookChapters path but it doesn't work, some suggestions?
[image]

```
export const createNewChapter = (bookId, inputText) => {
  return async dispatch => {
    dispatch(createNewChapterStart());
    try {
      const chaptersList = [];
      firebase
        .firestore()
        .doc(`Users/${bookId}/bookChapters/${inputText}`)
        .onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
          querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
            const chapters = doc.data().bookChapters;
            Object.keys(chapters).forEach(k => {
              chaptersList.push({ key: k, name: inputText });
            });
          });
        });
      dispatch(createNewChapterSuccess(inputText));
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch(createNewChapterFail(error));
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
};
```

Comment: Do you have any example screenshot with data inside? Your code won't work if you don't have any data that you can iterate over.

Comment: Does the answer by Dharmaraj solve your question?

Answer (score 1):

When you use `collection()`, it returns a [CollectionReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.collectionreference). In this case, it's pointing towards a sub-collection 'bookChapters' but it's a `map` as in your screenshot. If you want to iterate over that map, you need to fetch that document first and then read the `bookChapters` field.

```js
const chaptersList = [];
firebase
  .firestore()
  .doc(`Users/${bookId}`)
  .onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
    querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
      const chapters = doc.data().bookChapters
      Object.keys(chapters).forEach((k) => {
        chaptersList.push({key: k, name: chapters[k]});
      })
    });
  });
```

It might be better to store the list as an Array if you want to store all chapters in the same doc.

If you were trying to create a sub-collection, you can create one by clicking this button:

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but i was out for some days, i tried to use it but when i add a new chapters i have this error: Invalid collection reference. Collection references must have an odd number of segments, but Users/3yLoswEACAAJ has 2.

Comment: @ValerioBattilà yes it should be `.doc()` and not `.collection()`

Comment: ok with .doc it goes on but i have another error: ×
TypeError: querySnapshot.forEach is not a function

Comment: @ValerioBattilà `.doc()` listens to a single doc... if you are listening to whole collection then change to `.collection('Users')`

Comment: no, i have to iterate on the bookChapters document of a specific id (bookId), so .collection(`Users/${bookId}`) don't work

Comment: @ValerioBattilà your structure still isn't clear. Are you looking to store those in a sub-collection instead?

Comment: What i have to use for iterate inside a sub-collection? I'm not a good english talker i'm sorry

Comment: i have created a sub-collcetion, now what i use? Inside the sub-collection 'bookChapters' i want a list of all the chapters that i add, and on the document of each single chapter i want to add a string

Comment: @ValerioBattilà then you can use `.doc(\`Users/${bookId}/subColName/${chapterId}\`)`

Comment: When i add a new book i have to manually create a collection, how can i do that automatically?

Comment: i tried to use this code whit a collections open but i have the same error. querySnapshot.forEach

Comment: I can't see what the error is... can you update your questions with latest code and errors ?

Comment: done, we can try discord if you want, i'll do my best

Comment: @ValerioBattilà anything still missing from the _original_ question? If there's something new I'd recommend asking a new one. Thanks.